# How to use Google Map URL as a marker Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a simple app where customers send their service locations as URLs, like these:

- https://maps.app.goo.gl/XEUMo2diVTtJkine9
- https://g.co/kgs/zdGeB5
- https://maps.google.com/?cid=18234800435333057384
- https://maps.google.com/?q=Mullai+St%2C+Maharani+Avenue%2C+Vadavalli%2C+Tamil+Nadu+641041&ftid=0x3ba85f24ad71738d:0x9a062e23b86b557f

When a technician has a visit scheduled, they can just click on the link and Google shows a map to that one address.

The next thing I'd like to implement is showing several of these on a map together (like all of the technician's visits for the whole day). How do I place these address URls as markers on a map, using the Google Maps Javascript API?

Comment: If by *using the Google Maps Javascript API* you mean by using a documented method then the answer is that you can't.

Comment: Aside from the fact that the g.co link is not even a map URL, if you want to get the *final* URL, use a server side command such as cURL (url_effective) then extract lat/lng coordinates and add a Marker to a map using these with the API.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Please post your answer of "Not currently possible" and I will accept. I have tried many things with wget, curl, etc.. The problem is the final returned HTML (after many redirects) is not consistent. Sometimes the final HTML contains Javascript which has to be browser-executed before you get to the final URL with parseable coordinates. Bottom line, I can now get about 40% success with this "reverse engineering". Sorry for the non-map g.co URL, those are all user-submitted data and I picked a variety of URL formats without inspecting each one. Most are maps links. Thank you.

Comment: 1) Your question is closed so I can't post an answer 2) Read my comment again. You don't need the final HTML, only the URL. Google Maps final URLs always contain the coordinates. If for instance I run `curl -Ls -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective} https://maps.app.goo.gl/XEUMo2diVTtJkine9` it returns `https://www.google.com/maps/place/11.034785,77.015478/data=!4m6!3m5!1s0!7e2!8m2!3d11.034785!4d77.0154781?utm_source=mstt_1&entry=gps&lucs=swa` which should be enough to extract coordinates.

Comment: @MrUpsidown I know, but it's inconsistent. I have 114 URLs of which 41 return something containing lat/long, a 36% scraping success. Most have no coordinates embedded. Even copy-pasting your exact command into my console returns https://www.google.com/maps/place/GLK+INTERNATIONAL+COMPANY,+1,NGGO+Colony+Main+Road,V.I.P+nagar,Kurudampalayam,+Village,+Coimbatore,+Tamil+Nadu+641022/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x3ba8f7c1acae91d3:0xe9ca60a35d2c3aee?utm_source=mstt_1&entry=gps&lucs=swa.   (And re-curl'ing this URL doesn't help). So unless Google helps out, clients can just send coordinates. But thanks!

Answer (score -3):

I think you need to use this doc https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map

here exemple

```
function initMap() {
  // The location of Uluru
  const uluru = { lat: -25.344, lng: 13.031 };
  const other = { lat: -25.344, lng: 10.031 };
  // The map, centered at Uluru
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: uluru,
  });

  // The marker, positioned at first point
  const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map,
  });

  // The marker, positioned at second point
  const marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: other,
    map: map,
  });
}

window.initMap = initMap;
```

Comment: It's easy if you have the latitude & longitude. The question is how to add a marker using just a map URL, and without the latitude & longitude.